# The scanner is only reading the first line

Tags: java, input

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ArithmeticDemo {
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        int firstNumber;
        int secondNumber;
        int sum;
        int difference;
        int average;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Please enter a double >> 14");
        firstNumber = input.nextInt();
        System.out.print("Please enter another double >> 11 ");
        secondNumber = input.nextInt();
        sum = firstNumber + secondNumber;
        difference = firstNumber - secondNumber;
        average = sum / 2;
        System.out.println(firstNumber + " + " + secondNumber + " is " + sum);
        System.out.println(firstNumber + " - " + secondNumber + " is " + difference);
        System.out.println("The average of " + firstNumber + " and " + secondNumber + " is " + average);
    }
}
```

I am doing school homework and everything seems fine to me at glance I even took a break and came back but the code is supposed to display when executed

```
Please enter an integer >> 14
Please enter another integer >> 11
14 + 11 is 25
14 - 11 is 3
The average of 14 and 11 is 12
```

But when I execute it, it only reads

```
Please enter an integer >> 14
```

I am using Eclipse and it stats there is something wrong with my scanner input command but I am unsure of what it is, thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It runs as expected for me

```
Please enter a double >> 1414
Please enter another double >> 11 11
14 + 11 is 25
14 - 11 is 3
The average of 14 and 11 is 12
```

The number appears twice as you have it in your prompt. I suggest you change the code to

```
    System.out.print("Please enter a double >> ");
    firstNumber = input.nextInt();
    System.out.print("Please enter another double >> ");
    secondNumber = input.nextInt();
```

Comment: Okay, I'm new to programming and I'm using eclipse and dont completely understand the program yet but I made the edits and was able to get it to work thank you, you and Alex were right

Answer (score 1):

Your print statement should not contain the number there. It should only read "`System.out.print("Please enter a double >> ")`". That's the first problem. Also, your prompt reads "Please enter a double", but you are reading an integer. Change that line to `input.nextDouble()`. Otherwise, it runs completely as expected. It prints "Please enter a double >> ", I type a number, it prints the next line, I enter another number, and it outputs the information. Take a look at the docs for `java.util.Scanner` [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html)

Comment: Okay, I'm new to programming and I'm using eclipse and dont completely understand the program yet but I made the edits and was able to get it to work thank you, you and Peter were right

Answer (score 0):

Are you giving your program the input it needs to continue? As in Peters answer you are already printing 14 and haven't inputted it yet. I know its kind of silly but that might be why your program is hanging.

Comment: It is *exactly* why the program is not continuing.